# Get reference of performance object corresponding similar url concurrent requests - Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I figured out I can get the timings of the any XHR request from chrome using the performance API like this below which gives an array as an result (shows ho many requests of this resource has been made):

`performance.getEntriesByType('resource').filter(item => item.name.includes("https://myurl"))`

If I make 20 XHR requests parallely/concurrently, how do I differentiate which request performance is which object. Is there a way to get specific reference? I am using plain XHR request and am planning to use a RXJS stream if I am able to get a reference. Any help is welcome, I am new to this [API](https://w3c.github.io/performance-timeline/). I have attached the request and the result screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can add a query param in the url you are getting with a random string and so you can use the query param to match the request with the performance, even this can create server side cache issue.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks, this is achievable and should solve the purpose, I think. Cool. :-) Let me try this. But the best would be to add a reference point in the API itself. How adamant I am... ;-)